# Preg split multi SQL by semicolon in PHP

Tags: php, sql, split, preg-split

i am trying split my multi SQL by preg, but it doesn works...

Code:

```
$multiSql = "
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `typ` `typ` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=none; 1=test1; 2=test2; 3=test3';

ALTER TABLE `my_table2`
  ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
 
ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`; ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `test2` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `date`;

ALTER TABLE `my_table3` CHANGE `test2` `test2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=test; 1=test2;';
";

$sqlArray = preg_split('~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)(*F)|(?<=;)(?![ ]*$)~', trim($multiSql), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($sqlArray);
```

Demo:
https://ideone.com/nkvloT

I need output like this:

```
1. ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `typ` `typ` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=none; 1=test1; 2=test2; 3=test3';
2. ALTER TABLE `my_table2` ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
3. ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
4. ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `test2` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `date`;
5. ALTER TABLE `my_table3` CHANGE `test2` `test2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=test; 1=test2;';
```

I am using this pattern from diferend answer: `~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)(*F)|(?<=;)(?![ ]*$)~`
But it not works for my code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern can be written using a positive lookahead asserting whitespace chars until the end of the string instead.

You can also just use one of the two notations `(*FAIL)(*F)` instead of both.

```
\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=;)(?=\h*$|\s*\bALTER TABLE\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DOfJTl/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/l6677)

Example

```
$multiSql = "
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `typ` `typ` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=none; 1=test1; 2=test2; 3=test3';

ALTER TABLE `my_table2`
  ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
 
ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`; ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `test2` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `date`;

ALTER TABLE `my_table3` CHANGE `test2` `test2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=test; 1=test2;';
";

$sqlArray = array_map(function($x){
    return trim(preg_replace("/\R/", '', $x));
}, preg_split('~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=;)(?=\h*$|\s*\bALTER TABLE)~m', trim($multiSql), -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

print_r($sqlArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `typ` `typ` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=none; 1=test1; 2=test2; 3=test3';
    [1] => ALTER TABLE `my_table2`  ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
    [2] => ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `date` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `test`;
    [3] => ALTER TABLE `my_table3` ADD `test2` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL AFTER `date`;
    [4] => ALTER TABLE `my_table3` CHANGE `test2` `test2` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=test; 1=test2;';
)
```

Comment: Ohhh... Thank you so much. Would you still be able to modify the pattern in case it is not AFTER TABLE, but also INSERT, SELECT, etc.? SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE column = 'test ; test'; ALTER TABLE `my_table` CHANGE `typ` `typ` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=none; 1=test1; 2=test2; 3=test3';

Edit: okey it works for INSERT AND SELECT https://regex101.com/r/DOfJTl/2 Thx one more time.

Comment: @JeyC0b Parsing SQL with a regex is error prone. Can you create a regex101 example with those strings?

Comment: okey it works for INSERT AND SELECT https://regex101.com/r/DOfJTl/3 Thx one more time.

Comment: Done.
Here is my finaly pattern: '~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=;)(?=\h*$|\s*\bALTER|\s*\bSELECT|\s*\bINSERT|\s*\bUPDATE|\s*\bCREATE|\s*\bDELETE)~m'